# Plotting 2 data frames after merging

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have 2 different data frames that have the same column called `date`. Now, I want to plot these data frames where the values on `X` axis be the `date` column common to both the data frames and `Y` axis be the `value`. Also, I want to do this after concatenating both the data frames into a third frame. Currently here is what I did:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1,2,3,4,5], 'date': [20,40,60,80,100]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'value': [11,21,31,41,51], 'date': [20,40,60,80,100]})
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['df1','df2'], axis=1)
df3.plot()
plt.show()
```

but the resultant plot is not what I wanted. It generates 4 plots as could be seen from the legend.

[image]

How could I just have 2 plots with a common `X` axis and the difference reflected in the `Y` axis? Please note that I want to do this after concatenating the data frames `df1` and `df2` and by calling `plot` on `df3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the "date" column as index before concatenating.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1,2,3,4,5], 'date': [20,40,60,80,100]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'value': [11,21,31,41,51], 'date': [20,40,60,80,100]})
df3 = pd.concat([df1.set_index("date"), df2.set_index("date")], keys=['df1','df2'], axis=1)
df3.plot()
```

This creates a dataframe with only the two "value" columns and the date as index.
When plotting the index is used as x values and for each column a line is drawn.

[image]

You could also ignore the ignore the column index and later set new column names

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1.set_index("date"), df2.set_index("date")], axis=1, ignore_index =True)
df3.columns=['df1','df2']
```

[image]

Or you drop the level of the index that is common to both columns after concatenation.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1.set_index("date"), df2.set_index("date")], keys=['df1','df2'], axis=1)
df3.columns = df3.columns.droplevel(level=1)
```

Comment: Could you please explain what happened here?

Comment: How is the `x` and `y` axis choosen here?

Comment: Also, how could I avoid `None, None` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,on='date')
df3.plot.line(x="date")
plt.show()
```

[image]

First since the dates seem to be same, you can merge on the date column

```
df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,on='date')

   value_x  date  value_y
0        1    20       11
1        2    40       21
2        3    60       31
3        4    80       41
4        5   100       51
```

Another way to do it using matplotlib :
Plot the date vs value_x and date vs value_y

```
plt.plot(df3["date"],df3["value_x"],label="df1")
plt.plot(df3["date"],df3["value_y"],label="df2")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How could I do this with `df3.plot`? This is how I want to do.

Comment: @SuhailGupta Is there a particular reason why you have to use `df3.plot` ?

Comment: Yes. I need to utilize a built in function, that calls `plot` on the data frame object.

Comment: @SuhailGupta I've made some edits, check it out (added df.plot )